# How do I get 'import' to work in a web page over file:// protocol

Tags: ecmascript-6

Most browsers support 'import', so the following should work:

```
/**
* Adder.mjs
*/

class Adder {

    add(n1, n2) {
        return n1 + n2;
    }
}

export default Adder;
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Import Test</title>
<script type="module">
    import Adder from "./Adder.mjs";
    var adder = new Adder();
    var result = adder.add(1, 1);
    console.log("Result: " + result.toString());
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It however results in the following error (Chromium debug console):

```
Access to script at 'file:///home/gso/eclipse-workspace/Test/Adder.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: The response is invalid.
test.html:7 GET file:///home/gso/eclipse-workspace/Test/Adder.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Have you checked that you are referencing `Adder.mjs` instead of `Adder.js`? Also, your code has `Class` instead of `class` in `Adder.mjs`.

Comment: Is the file `Adder.mjs` in the `Test` folder? And is the case of the name correct? Not `adder.mjs`

Comment: Modules don't work over the `file://` protocol. You need a webserver.

Comment: Installed apache and loaded the web page, following error in console: Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: That usually means you have a 404. Check the network tab.

Comment: Adder.mjs has a status of '304 Not Modified' in the network tab.  Otherwise it looks OK.

Comment: @user5321531, I guess Apache is not serving the right mime type, try: `npx serve` on that folder (assuming you have node installed)

Comment: I changed the file extension of the script from Adder.mjs to Adder.js, and it worked fine.  Apache must determine the file type from the extension (not supporting .mjs).

Answer (score -1):

As connexo pointed out:

> "Modules don't work over the file:// protocol. You need a webserver."

It's also worth noting that Apache does not support the .mjs file extension, ES6 modules have to be suffixed .js.